How does gz sim headless rendering work?
I'm trying to launch my simulation headless because, for now all I need is the data
I'm doing gz sim -s --headless-rendering world.sdf but for some reason, I can't understand it is like the simulation doesn't start
When I have a GUI I click on the start button but I assumed that when running headless it would start automatically but it isn't happening
Any ideas? Or is this a bug?
Im using Ubuntu 24.04 with gazebo harmonic and ros2 jazzy
If you need any more information please let me know
Best Regards!

Update:
Find some documentation on how to run gazebo as a server: https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/server_config.html
And with the flag -r the simulation starts automatically
Quoting: "though the simulation is running (started with -r)"
Hope this helps someone!
